# why i am getting error in the second one but not in the first one?

Tags: javascript, scope

In the latter, why there is an error showing that 'c' is not defined? Is it just because I have written 'var' keyword before variable `c`?

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  c = a + b;
}

sum(10, 20)
document.write(c);

function sum(a, b) {
  var c = a + b;
}

sum(10, 20)
document.write(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things happening here.

In JavaScript, if there are multiple functions with the same name, only the last function will be the one used. In your example, the one with the `var` is used while the first one is ignored. This is because JavaScript "hoists" variable and function declarations up to the beginning of each scope. Despite being an interpreted language, the code is first analyzed, and this "hoisting" is part of that process.

Using `var` to declare a variable limits it to a local scope. In your second function, you are limiting `c` to be usable only within that function. If you remove the `var`, c will be a global variable and would thus be accessible from outside the function. (I recommend using `var` and `let` all the time to avoid confusion with global variables. Furthermore, in your example functions, they should ideally return values instead of setting a global variable.)

The error is occurring on line 6: the first `document.write(c);` Because you used `var` in the second function, `c` is not available as a global variable, so the code fails with `ReferenceError: c is not defined`.

Comment: `let` and `const`. `var` should be considered obsolete.

Comment: I think `var` can still have a place for people who are used to using Python (and Django), whose default scopes are more like `var` than `let` when it comes to `if`, `for`, and `while`. (Function scoping instead of block scoping.)